# issue while adding glide dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-glide

I wrote a program in android with java, when I add the Glide dependencies

`implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'`

my android studio begins to give me this error:

**"ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-fragment
Affected Modules: app**

**ERROR: Failed to resolve: animated-vector-drawable
Affected Modules: app"**

this is my app bulid.gradle with the error shown

[image]

I looked for any similar answer past week and try them all but I wasn't able to solve this problem,
when I remove the Glide dependencies, everything comes back to normal again.

**this is my app module build.gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mohammad.kahgle"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}    
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.armcha:ElasticView:0.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.nightonke:boommenu:2.1.1'
implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: can you post your app module build.gradle

Comment: Have you already have `defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}` ?

Comment: @dardardardar i added that to question

Comment: @ADM yes and no change

Comment: try `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` in glide dependency

Comment: @HelloWorld ty but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem. if you don't use animated vector drawable with glide use this code to exclude useless dependencies :

```
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"){
    exclude group: 'androidx.vectordrawable', module: 'vectordrawable-animated'
}
```

happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

solving this problem in minsdkversion 21 and targetsdkversion 29 with below libraries:

add these to dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-rc04'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
```

and downgrade the glide version to 4.8.0

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.gradle file. for details see download section of  [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}
```

Comment: where did you put this in your build.gradle? I don't see.

Comment: yes i do that before , no solution on internet work for me

Answer (score 0):

In your app module enable vectorDrawables useSupportLibrary

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

Then add this in dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: i do that and got this too 
ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation group: 'androidx.fragment', name: 'fragment', version: '1.1.0'
implementation group: 'androidx.vectordrawable', name: 'vectordrawable-animated', version: '1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to delete the caches folder inside `~/.gradle` and download the dependencies again.

Add:

```
 implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-alpha04' 
 implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0' 
 implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
```

to `app/gradle`